How to map GCP instance types to compatible disk types programmatically?
I am working on a system where users select GCP instance types, and I need to ensure compatibility with the appropriate disk types (e.g., pd-standard, pd-balanced, or pd-ssd).
I am looking for a way to programmatically map instance types (e.g., e2-medium, n2-standard-4) to their supported disk types. Specifically:

Does Google Cloud provide an API or dataset that lists the supported disk types for each instance type?
If no direct mapping exists, is there a standard practice for deriving compatibility based on machine series (e.g., E2, N2, N1)?

Any guidance or sample implementations would be greatly appreciated!

Google Cloud does not provide a direct API to map instance types to their supported disk types explicitly, but you can derive this information from the following resource.
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-resource#machine_type_comparison
Based on the above information you can map the compatibility with the machine type.
